# Can't get CSS loaded in Master page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I am trying to simply load a .css file from within the master page.

The master page Admin.Master and the css file AdminView.css are both in the /views/shared folder.  I am sticking the following link tag in the  section of my Master page.

I have tried both:

```
<link href="<%: ResolveUrl("AdminView.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and

```
<link href="AdminView.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

As well as every other combination (~/views/shared/adminview.css OR /adminview.css....etc)

and when viewing in Firebug what it loads, it always returns "Resource not found".

NOTE: I have double checked the name and spelling.

Its these trival stuff that shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Try using <%:Url.Content("~/views/shared/adminview.css")> ~ symbol is only meaningful in server side script and you have to give paths relative to server root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access resources in the Views folder directly from the web.  You should put your content in the Content folder (or Content/Styles) and reference it from there.  The Views folder is for the framework to use to find your Views, it isn't visible from the web.

```
<link href="<%: Url.Content( "~/content/styles/adminview.css" ) %>" ... />
```

Comment: So I have tried all these options and the Url.Content returns a URL of localurl.com/Account/Logon?ReturnURL=%2Content%2AdminViews.css. Which is wrong.  However the error on the page is no longer stating "resource not found" but "Failed to load...."

Comment: @pghtech - Sounds like you are denying access to anonymous users in your web.config -- you shouldn't be.  You should allow access and use the AuthorizeAttribute to control access to your controllers.  I doubt if the Url helper is generating that URL, I suspect that it's getting a redirect from your site.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="/views/shared/AdminView.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```