# Trying to set security on Controllers and Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

So I am having this issue of getting CSS files applied through the masterpage.  I had another question: [Can't get CSS loaded in Master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211241/cant-get-css-loaded-in-master-page) that helped me to apply the link tag correctly (or different options).

This is confirmed in Firebug where the call is coming back 302 found, but the styles are not being applied.

This question lead to another contributor pointing out possible access issues to the controller/content in my Web.config.  Thus the reason for this question separate "Security" related question.

I have went through a number of full MVC app tutorials such as NerdDinner (v.1, v.2) and Pro MVC 2's not to mentioned a good bit of reading material in my pursuit to learn ASP.NET MVC - and I have not come across any details on access to sources such as /Content to anonymous users just to load css files.  Nor have I read anything that MVC takes the approach that it is entirely locked down and you must open specific areas to specific roles/users/everyone OR open it all up for everyone.

So I still have the problem of not being able to get CSS rules applied even though it shows that the .css file is being found (302).  But another issue is that I am seeing a second call to load the file in the console:

```
localurl.com/Account/Logon?ReturnURL=%2Content%2AdminViews.css
```

But errors with a 500.

Now I have commented out the logon URL line in my web.config "Authentication" section, and there is no route that I can see in my route dictionary.

Any thoughts on both of these related issues?

**UPDATE**

I found that the problem with why the redirection to the

```
localurl.com/login.aspx?returnurl=content/adminview.css
```

was that theforms authentication (in IIS) was enabled with the properties set to "Login.aspx".  Changing this generated an ACL rights (yellow screen of death) when accessing the file directly

```
localurl.com/contents/adminview.css
```

I found adding users to the content directory (i.e. IUSR account) would rectify this issue.

So I now need to find what the proper way to set security.  What account I should use ...etc.  I did already have the IUSR_ComputerName already given access, which my understanding is the default IIS anonymous user account.  So why this wouldn't be enough to access resources in the ~/contents/ directory is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

You could allow access to these resources using web.config.

```
 <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I have done this.  but I was already loading the resource as mentioned before making this change, but it still doesn't get applied, and i still have the problem with the second call where it is trying to direct to account/logon?returnurl=/contents/adminview.css

Comment: Can you load the css directly? EG: localurl/contents/adminview.css? (assuming that is the correct url from your info)

Comment: also it would help if you post the code showing the criteria for denying access to a user

Comment: The problem was that the anonymous forms authentication was enabled with a form "Login.aspx" set.  Changing this generated an ACL rights issue with accessing the file directly (i.e. localurl.com/contents/adminview.css).  Adding users to the content directory (i.e. IUSR account).  So I now need to find what the proper way to set security.  I am going to update my question, since it still addresses security issues.